# How to join lists within lists in Python based on a common element

Tags: python, list, join

I have two lists of lists:

```
List1 = [['Jack','27','cat','house','fireman'], ['Tom','43','cat','Flat','Doctor'], ['Ben','30','Dog','house','Postman']]

List2 = [['Orange','5','Tom'], ['Blue','11','Ben'], ['Red','21','Jack']]
```

I want to join the lists together where the name matches:

```
Result_list = [['Jack','27','cat','house','fireman','Red','21','Jack'], ['Tom','43','cat','Flat','Doctor','Orange','5','Tom'], ['Ben','30','Dog','house','Postman','Blue','11','Ben']]
```

The names will always be at position [0] within the lists in list1 and [2] within the lists in list2

I'm am pretty new to python and cannot work out how to do this. Is anyone able to offer a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach by converting one of the list to a `dict`.

```
List1 = [['Jack','27','cat','house','fireman'], ['Tom','43','cat','Flat','Doctor'], ['Ben','30','Dog','house','Postman']]
List2 = [['Orange','5','Tom'], ['Blue','11','Ben'], ['Red','21','Jack']]

List2_d = {i[-1]: i for i in List2}
for j in List1:
    if j[0] in List2_d:
        j.extend(List2_d[j[0]])

print(List1)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Jack', '27', 'cat', 'house', 'fireman', 'Red', '21', 'Jack'],
 ['Tom', '43', 'cat', 'Flat', 'Doctor', 'Orange', '5', 'Tom'],
 ['Ben', '30', 'Dog', 'house', 'Postman', 'Blue', '11', 'Ben']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [['Jack','27','cat','house','fireman'], 
['Tom','43','cat','Flat','Doctor'], 
['Ben','30','Dog','house','Postman']]

list2 = [['Orange','5','Tom'], ['Blue','11','Ben'], ['Red','21','Jack']]

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i[0] == j[2]:
            i.extend(j)
print(list1)
```

output:

```
[['Jack', '27', 'cat', 'house', 'fireman', 'Red', '21', 'Jack'],
 ['Tom', '43', 'cat', 'Flat', 'Doctor', 'Orange', '5', 'Tom'],
 ['Ben', '30', 'Dog', 'house', 'Postman', 'Blue', '11', 'Ben']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a dictionary as in index to List2 and build the merged list with a comprehension on List1 that concatenates the matching sublist in the dictionary:

```
List1 = [['Jack','27','cat','house','fireman'], ['Tom','43','cat','Flat','Doctor'], ['Ben','30','Dog','house','Postman']]
List2 = [['Orange','5','Tom'], ['Blue','11','Ben'], ['Red','21','Jack']]

match  = { sl[2]:sl for sl in List2 }
merged = [ sl+match[sl[0]] for sl in List1 ]
```

output:

```
print(merged)

[['Jack', '27', 'cat', 'house', 'fireman', 'Red', '21', 'Jack'],
 ['Tom', '43', 'cat', 'Flat', 'Doctor', 'Orange', '5', 'Tom'],
 ['Ben', '30', 'Dog', 'house', 'Postman', 'Blue', '11', 'Ben']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `defaultdict` to group by the names:

```
from collections import defaultdict

List1 = [['Jack','27','cat','house','fireman'], ['Tom','43','cat','Flat','Doctor'], ['Ben','30','Dog','house','Postman']]

List2 = [['Orange','5','Tom'], ['Blue','11','Ben'], ['Red','21','Jack']]

d = defaultdict(list)
for lst in List1:
    d[lst[0]].extend(lst)

for lst in List2:
    d[lst[-1]].extend(lst)

print([v for v in d.values()])
```

Since both lists are of the same length, we can also get away with `zip` here:

```
d = defaultdict(list)

for x, y in zip(List1, List2):
    d[x[0]].extend(x)
    d[y[-1]].extend(y)

print([v for v in d.values()])
```

**Output:**

```
[['Jack', '27', 'cat', 'house', 'fireman', 'Red', '21', 'Jack'], ['Tom', '43', 'cat', 'Flat', 'Doctor', 'Orange', '5', 'Tom'], ['Ben', '30', 'Dog', 'house', 'Postman', 'Blue', '11', 'Ben']]
```